# What's the MSBuild flag to store recently compiled build to a specified location?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, msbuild, flags

I want to store build in a specified folder other than the MSBuild default folder. Is there a MSBuild flag to do so? If yes, then what's the flag and how to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `-p:OutDir=..\foo\bar` to specify an output location.

For some projects there may be an issue (e.g. mixed ASP.NET Core and .NET Framework) with that and `OutputPath` can be used instead. It's a bit of a mess due to a stuck transition (see https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/87)